# How to keep text beside the text field in html page

Tags: html, forms

Trying with the below code but not getting exact output.
Can someone please help me here?

```
<head>
    <title>question3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        name:<input type="text" name="hjcg"><p style="text-align: right">jgdfiuhio hjgiofhuorgfo gfd7uyte8u7tr98gt</p>
        username::<input type="text" name="hjcg"><span style="text-align: right">hjgdfiuhio hjgiofhuorgfo gfd7uyte8u7tr98gt</span>
    </body>
</html>![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCSnC.jpg)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQkvB.jpg)
```

Answer (score 0):

<p> tags are block level elements which makes them full width on a new line.
To make them appear on the same line as other elements, you can style them as inline or inline-block elements or use elements that are inline like <span>

To make elements appear on the next line you can use <div> tags which are block level elements by default (which you can change too using css)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>question3</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      name:<input type="text" name="hjcg">
      <span style="text-align: right">jgdfiuhio hjgiofhuorgfo gfd7uyte8u7tr98gt</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      username:<input type="text" name="hjcg">
      <span style="text-align: right">hjgdfiuhio hjgiofhuorgfo gfd7uyte8u7tr98gt</span>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Flex should fix your issue, but you should definitely consider using an external css file.
You can add it to your html page with:

`<link href="your_style_file.css" rel="stylesheet">`

then you could try:

```
form{
    display: flex;
}
```

or even better, giving your form a class or an id like

```
<form id="my-form">
```

or

```
<form class="these-forms">
```

and then

```
#my-form{
    display: flex;
}
```

or

```
.these-forms{
    display: flex;
}
```

Please check [**FlexBoxFroggy**](https://flexboxfroggy.com/) if you want to learn Flex basics in minutes.

What you are doing actually with `text-align` is align text **within** its container.
What you want in aligning items inside the form. Displaying the form as Flex will help you do that.